# Default behaviours of browsers, preventDefault

Tags: javascript, browser

Is there a list or documentation of the browser's default behaviours which can be prevented by using preventDefault?
(Eg submit button, link a....)
Greeting

Comment: [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) ?

Comment: All events with `cancelable: true` properties can be prevented by `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use `Event.cancalable` to check if the event you would like to prevent, can actually be stopped by `Event.preventDefault`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/cancelable

Comment: Noted. But i am looking for more information about what will happen. Another example touch events. There are default behaviours too. I found this homepage. [Quirksmode](https://www.quirksmode.org/mobil3/default.html). I am looking for an overview of default behaviours.

Comment: Have you tried looking into [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=touch%20events) page? There are support tables on which browser this event can be supported and act as expected. In other case it mostly translates to click event if it's not supported (from the css perspective a hover or active status)